# Selenium - findElement

Tags: selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF0Id.png)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getCssValue("backgroundColor");
```

Only finds the element and does not return the cssvalue. I also tried `.isEnabled()`, and `.isDisplayed()` just to see if it will work but the same happens. It only finds the element and does not proceed.

Comment: what is your specific question ?

Comment: @cruisepandey you're right. Here is the same as comment. Answer has been deleted. --> From your very poor input the only thing I can tell you is, that backgroundColor is wrong. It must be named background-color.

If this does not work you should provide more info (html structure, etc)

Comment: @mariamakiling Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try below example for getCssValue with selenium

```
public class Test123 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
            String baseURL = "http://www.google.com";
            Driver.get(baseURL);
            Driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
            System.out.println("Color of a button before mouse hover: " + Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]")).getCssValue("color"));
       try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does your example help mariamakiling? You do basically the same. The main difference is that you are using By.name() instead of xpath()....

Comment: @JosefBiehler: Even if we use xpath it will work. Please find above modified solution with xpath.